# What is the recommended way to upgrade elementary OS 0.2 Luna to 0.3 Freya?

Tags: release-freya, luna, updates

How can I upgrade from elementary OS Luna to Freya without losing my data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> At the moment elementary isn't providing an upgrade path from update manager since results are mixed. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. You can try:
>
> 1. Back up EVERYTHING.
> 2. [Make a Freya install disk](https://elementary.io/docs/installation).
> 3. Boot from the install disk and select the "upgrade" option.
>
> However, as I said, results may vary. *It's always recommended to perform a clean install*. An upgrade will not give you the exact same experience as a clean install since it won't overwrite your personal settings. This is important for new features like tab naming in Terminal.

[Source, Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198340/upgrading-elementary-os-to-freya). Posted 2015-04-24, so the information is up to date.

As said, clean installs are often safer as they reset everything and nothing will conflict. If there is any way you can, try to do a new install.

For backing up, I recommend CrashPlan, and trust it when I reinstall. [Instructions for installation on Linux](http://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/Latest/Getting_Started/Installing_The_CrashPlan_App#Linux).

Comment: This must be the first OS where a full reinstall is considered the safe option. I was about to install EOS as it looks absolutely delicious, but this...

A clean install also means new UIDs, a reinstallation of all packages, a reconfiguration of all packages, etc. At the very least EOS should be considering some kind of "back up and install package list/settings" if "clean install" is going to be the norm.

Shame. Such a good looking thing.

Answer (score 4):

There is no officially supported way to upgrade to freya at the moment.

I recommend you to do a clean install, but keep the `/home` partition the same and create a user with the same name as in your Luna installation.

By doing so, you'll keep all of the files you've stored and most of the application settings (although you'll probably have install them again for the settings to be applied).

Comment: What if there is no separate home partition?

Comment: @user3 If you're doing a clean install, you can create new partitions at that moment.

Comment: What makes the switch from luna -> freya or now freya -> loki a little bit more comfortable is to use [Aptik Migration Utility](http://www.teejeetech.in/p/aptik.html)